# Deploying a firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

i'm trying to deploy my functions on firebase and it says "parssing error unexpected token", I have been stucked here since two days, thanks. Here is the image ---->

[image]

Comment: looks issue with eslint rules, tell us about `babel-eslint` version & configuration you are using.

Comment: Could you share a bit of your code where the crash occurs?

Comment: Actually it is an eslint issue. It took me several time to solve it. Thanks sir